# Java jetty перегрузка

Tags: java, jetty

использую jetty для back-end. до этого писал небольшие проекты, а сейчас хочу перейти на новый уровень. В связи с этим задался вопросами:

- как jetty справляется с перегрузками и как вообще реагирует?
- есть ли у jetty защита от атак если есть то как она работает?

Answer (score 1):

Несмотря на то, что с 9-й версии Jetty стал асинхронным сервером и сильно ускорился, он всё ещё проигрывает по производительности Undertow. А до Netty вообще как до Луны.

Не знаю, что именно вы подразумеваете под защитой от атак, могу только предполагать. И обычно подобное приходиться писать самому, на любом сервере.

**P.S.** Скорее всего вы упрётесь в ограничения производительности на уровне бизнес-логики задолго до того, как исчерпаете возможности сервера.

Comment: Вопрос по поводу асинхронности, насколько я знаю его суть заключается в использовании буфера. Можно ли как-то конфигурировать его размер  что бы защитить от перегрузки

Comment: Нет, грубо говоря, суть заключается в том, что раньше использовался пул потоков, а теперь в одном потоке крутится epoll-селектор.